# Android gridview not maintaining element order (unless sacrificing performance)

Tags: java, android, performance, gridview

In my application i have a gallery, a gridview containing imageviews. The code is as follows:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {  
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(LAYOUT_WIDTH, LAYOUT_HEIGHT));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inSampleSize = 5;
        Bitmap previewBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
                        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picture_paths[position], o), 
                        LAYOUT_WIDTH, 
                        LAYOUT_HEIGHT, 
                        false);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(previewBitmap);
        return imageView;
    }
```

Ofcourse, the performance of this is pretty much horrible as it has to resize and load a bitmap every time an element is drawn. However, if i move the resize-code inside the if(convertView == null) block, the order of the elements is not maintained - every image changes position constantly as the user scrolls through the gridview.

What is the proper way to do this without having performance issues?

Comment: Use an AsyncTask or more simply use the project on Github called Universal Image Loader by nostra i guess.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about UIL, looks very cool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you get a convertView that's not null, you need to rebind data. This means you need to keep a reference to your scaled bitmaps somewhere else (in your adapter, in a bitmap cache, etc.)